# How to add function with a name supplied as string to a class in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, class

I have a couple of classes whose methods all follow the same structure. For the sake of the example lets say it is

```
class Foo:
    def say_hello(self,a,b,c,d) : print("hello" + a + b + c + d)
    def say_moo(self,a,b,c,d) : print("moo" + a + b + c + d)
    def say_foo(self,a,b,c,d) : print("foo" + a + b + c + d)
    # more of the same pattern...

class Bar:
    def say_hello(self,a,b,c,d) : print("hello" + a + b + c + d)
    def say_bar(self,a,b,c,d) : print("bar" + a + b + c + d)
    def say_boo(self,a,b,c,d) : print("boo" + a + b + c + d)

#more classes of the same pattern...
```

Having those methods is a requirement, so simply using a `def say_x(self,x,a,b,c,d) : print(x + a + b + c + d)` is not a solution unfortunately.

I would like to avoid repeating myself that much and am looking for a way to write something along the line of

```
class Foo :
   def SOME_MAGIC("hello")
   def SOME_MAGIC("moo")
   def SOME_MAGIC("foo")
```

that would result in the equivalent of the above `Foo`. Searching for the topic, I always reach something with meta classes, but they always come with the note saying: "If you wonder whether you need them, you don't.". Hence apparently I do not need them. What do I need instead?

Comment: You could use inheritance to your advantage here. Make the classes `Foo` and `Bar` inherit `SOME_MAGIC` from another separate class, like `BarStool`.

Comment: @HampusLarsson most of the methods are different in `Foo` and `Bar` (and the others), there are only few exceptions. I know I could move `say_hello` to a base class, but thats about it what I know how to use inheritance here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, you can use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
from functools import partial
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):     
        cmds = ('hello', 'moo', 'boo')  # only define your strings once
        for c in cmds:
            setattr(self, f'say_{c}', partial(self.say, c))

    def say(self, x, a, b, c, d):
        print(x + a + b + c + d)
```

Test:

```
>>> f = Foo()
>>> f.say_hello(*'abcd')
helloabcd
>>> f.say_boo(*'1234')
boo1234
```

The benefit is you only have to define your strings once.  The drawback is the readability is less apparent.

If `say()` is universal between classes, you might even do this:

```
from functools import partialmethod

def add_say(cls, *cmds:str):
    def say(self, x, a, b, c, d):
        print(x, a, b, c, d)
        # ... do something with self if you need ...

    for cmd in cmds:
        setattr(cls, f'say_{cmd}', partialmethod(say, cmd))

class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        add_say(Foo, 'hello', 'moo', 'boo')

class Bar:
    def __init__(self):
        add_say(Bar, 'hello', 'bar', 'baz')
```

Test:

```
>>> f = Foo()
>>> f.say_boo(*'abcd')
boo a b c d
>>> b = Bar()
>>> b.say_baz(*'dude')
baz d u d e
```

Comment: OP tagged their question python2.7 and i don't think format strings or type annotations are compatible. the execution of either solution would create and bind new partial functions _every time an instance is created_. the methods wouldn't exist in the class at all in the first solution. both of these solutions are bad, in my opinion.

Comment: and with the latter solution, the method wouldn't exist in the class dict until an instance is created. this could lead to unexpected issues: an exception-free execution of `Foo.say_hello( Foo(), *range(4) )` would depend on whether an instance of Foo has been created before it.

Comment: Fair enough, I didn't catch the python2.7 tag.  However I'd argue that the most obvious and clear solution here is just to write all the `say_whatever` methods out as it's much clearer, readable, and manageable across the codebase.  IMO the requirement of forcing a different `say_whatever` method that does borderline the same thing is a design decision that should be revisited, but that's obviously out of OP's hands.

Answer (score 1):

You’re looking for [`functools.partialmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partialmethod)

```
class Foo:
    def say(self, first, a, b, c, d) : 
        print(first, a, b, c, d)

    say_hello = functools.partialmethod(say, 'hello')
```

Comment: i was hoping that I can write `hello` only once, but this is close enough

Answer (score 0):

```
from __future__ import print_function

class SayMetaClass( type ):
    def __new__( mcls, name, bases, dict_ ):
        say_template = lambda value: lambda self, a, b, c, d: print( value + a + b + c + d )

        if "SAY_WHAT" in dict_:
            for value in dict_[ "SAY_WHAT" ]:
                method_name = "say_{value}".format( value=value )
                if method_name in dict_:
                    raise ValueError( "{method_name} is already defined in the class!".format( method_name=method_name ) )
                dict_[ method_name ] = say_template( value )

            del dict_[ "SAY_WHAT" ]

        return super( SayMetaClass, mcls ).__new__( mcls, name, bases, dict_ )

class Foo( object ):
    __metaclass__ = SayMetaClass

    SAY_WHAT = [ "hello", "moo", "foo" ]

class Bar( object ):
    __metaclass__ = SayMetaClass

    SAY_WHAT = [ "hello", "bar", "boo" ]

class Baz( Foo, Bar ):
    pass

args = "1234"

f = Foo()
f.say_hello( *args )
f.say_moo( *args )
f.say_foo( *args )

b = Baz()
b.say_hello( *args )
b.say_moo( *args )
b.say_bar( *args )
```

The code would need adapting for Python 3 compatibility.

I deliberately avoided the use of functools helpers. I'd **discourage** the code above, because it makes stack traces more verbose, defeats static analysis tools, makes dynamic introspection more difficult and is generally more confusing that the less dynamic approaches.